# Performance penalty between for loop and Parallel.For() with MaxDegreeOfParallelism of 1

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library

I want to do something like the following:

```
int firstLoopMaxThreads = 1; // or -1
int secondLoopMaxThreads = firstLoopMaxThreads == 1 ? -1 : 1;

Parallel.For(0, m, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = firstLoopMaxThreads }, i =>
{
    //do some processor and/or memory-intensive stuff
    Parallel.For(0, n, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = secondLoopMaxThreads }, j =>
    {
        //do some other processor and/or memory-intensive stuff
    });
});
```

Would it be worth it, performance wise, to swap the inner Parallel.For loop with a normal for loop when secondLoopMaxThreads = 1? What is the performance difference between a regular for loop and a Parallel.For loop with MaxDegreeofParallelism = 1?

Comment: AFAIK the only difference is that a `Parallel.For` loop will be scheduled to run on a thread pool thread (and that probably incurs some scheduling overhead). Other than that the body of the loop should perform equally well in both scenarios. ICBWT.

Comment: Side note: make sure to check out [Which is faster](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert to make [performance] question better...

Comment: Whether or not its worth it is primarily a function of how much you care about performance in this context.  That's not something we can tell you.  The performance different could be enough to matter, or it could not.  Only you can answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many iterations you're talking about and what level of performance you're talking about to answer whether it is worth it or not. In your context is 1ms considered a lot, or a little?

I did a rudimentary test as below (since Thread.Sleep is not entirely accurate.. although the for loop measured 15,000ms to within 1ms everytime). Over 15,000 iterations repeated 5 times it generally added about 4ms of overhead compared to a standard for loop... but of course results would be different depending on the environment.

```
for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
{
    int iterations = 15000;

    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)        
        Thread.Sleep(1);        

    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("#{0}:Elapsed (for): {1:#,0}ms", z, ((double)s.ElapsedTicks / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000);

    var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 };
    s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    Parallel.For(0, iterations, options, (i) => Thread.Sleep(1));

    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("#{0}: Elapsed (parallel): {1:#,0}ms", z, ((double)s.ElapsedTicks / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Sleep is accurate to the systems timer resolution. You probably had Chrome running or a media player that sets the resolution to 1ms. That said, there is something about this benchmark that warps the results. 1ms of overhead is extreme. Don't use Sleep.

Comment: I don't say anywhere something has a 1ms of overhead.. not sure what you're referring to.. my point was if I try to sleep for 1ms 15,000 times and the loop takes 15,000ms in total to within 1ms, sleep is reasonably constant.

Comment: Ah, I understood your last paragraph to say that 4ms overhead were added per item for 5 loop runs. OK, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The loop *body* performs equally well in both versions but the loop itself is drastically slower with `Parallel.For` even for single-threaded execution. Each element needs to call a delegate. This is very much slower than incrementing a loop counter.

If your loop body does anything meaningful the loop overhead will be dwarfed by useful work. Just ensure that your work items are not too small and you won't notice a difference.

Nesting parallel loops is rarely a good idea. A single parallel loop is usually best enough provided the work items are neither too small nor too big.

Comment: Nesting parallel loops is almost never a good idea, I agree.  I specifically have the example code set up in such a way that the two loops never both run in parallel, though, only one or the other.  Do you still consider such a setup a bad idea, and if so, why?

Comment: In that case it is less of a bad idea. You suffer the single-threaded overhead of a parallel loop, that's all. Make your work items bigger and you don't need to worry about overhead.